# How to get current page's url content using api in jira?

Tags: java, url, groovy, jira

I need to get the url address of the current page using the Behaviours Plugin. Does anyone know how to do this in groovy using the jira api? Note, my jira version is 4.4.1.

Comment: url of which page? waht do you mean by current?

Comment: You don't need a JIRA method to get the page request url; you can get it from a Java method, right?

Comment: i try to use request object,but failed,the error message is:     2012-06-19 12:12:19,578 http-8079-7 ERROR jirauser 732x2224x1 1mkelx5 127.0.0.1 /rest/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours/1.0/behaviours/runvalidator.json [onresolve.jira.groovy.BehaviourManagerImpl] Found class  but could not find method run
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: request for class: Script1